# Javascript Copy Clipboard function which works perfectly on all latest browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got below cocpy clipboard function which works perfectly on latest Internet Explorer as well as Latest Firefox.

```
function copyToClipboardCrossbrowser(s) 
{           
        //s = document.getElementById(s).value;               

        if( window.clipboardData && clipboardData.setData )
        {
            clipboardData.setData("Text", s);
        }           
        else
        {
            // You have to sign the code to enable this or allow the action in about:config by changing
            //user_pref("signed.applets.codebase_principal_support", true);
            netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege('UniversalXPConnect');

            var clip = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/widget/clipboard;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIClipboard);
            if (!clip) return;

            // create a transferable

            var trans = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/widget/transferable;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsITransferable);
            if (!trans) return;

            // specify the data we wish to handle. Plaintext in this case.
            trans.addDataFlavor('text/unicode');

            // To get the data from the transferable we need two new objects
            var str = new Object();
            var len = new Object();

            var str = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/supports-string;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsISupportsString);

            str.data= s;        

            trans.setTransferData("text/unicode",str, str.data.length * 2);

            var clipid=Components.interfaces.nsIClipboard;              
            if (!clip) return false;
            clip.setData(trans,null,clipid.kGlobalClipboard);      
        }
}
```

Can you please suggest what changes I need to do in above function so that works perfectly on safari as well as opera.

I know there is way if we install shockwave on these browsers using flash to get copied data. I just don't want to go for flash solution.

Thanks.

Best Regards,
Manoj

Comment: It's my understanding that some browsers (including Opera) simply don't allow JavaScript to access the clipboard (for security reasons).

Comment: @nnnnnn, I am aware of this that why looking for some good solution.

Comment: When you said you "don't want to go for flash solution" I assumed you meant you wanted a JS-only answer, so then the answer is "You can't".

Comment: zClip is a good flash solution... But if you're insistent on no flash, you'll have to re-read nnnnnn's comment.

Comment: @ok...what are the code changes we need to get it working with falsh